# Display column header value if data is being pulled from specific column

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have two sheets in my workbook – **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**.

**Sheet1** has two columns and six rows.

```
    A        B
1 [MARK]    [LUCY]
2 100       120
3 200       220
4 300       320
5 400       420
6 500       520

[Sheet1]
```

**Sheet2** has two columns that I'm attempting to pull data into from Sheet1 using an IF statement and VLOOKUP.

In cell `Sheet2-A2` I am pulling in a reference from any cell in Sheet1 from row 2 down. 
So the following example will pull in the value of 100:

```
    A                 B
1 [VALUE]           [NAME]
2 =Sheet1!A2
3 
4 
5 

[Sheet2]
```

In `Sheet2-B2` i'm trying to include an IF statement that says:

IF value in cell `Sheet2-A2` is pulling from `Sheet1-ColumnA`, then print the value **MARK** in cell `Sheet2-B2`.
IF value in cell `Sheet2-A3` is pulling from `Sheet1-ColumnB`, then print the value **LUCY** in cell `Sheet2-B3`.
IF value in cell `Sheet2-A4` is pulling from `Sheet1-ColumnA`, then print the value **MARK** in cell `Sheet2-B4`.
And so on, so the result looks something like this:

```
    A           B
1 [VALUE]     [NAME]
2 100          MARK
3 220          LUCY
4 400          MARK
5 520          LUCY

[Sheet2]
```

I'm not sure if VLOOKUP is the right way to do this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you always 'pulling' data from sheet1 with the formula given in your example?  Are the values in sheet1 col A always unique/numeric? Are the values in sheet1 col A in always ascending order?

Comment: 1. Yes always pulling from Sheet, 2. Yes values are always going to be be unique and numeric, 3. No they are not always in ascending order...........
I think that it could possibly be solved by including the search function in cell 'Sheet2-B2'...........

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("!A",A1)),Sheet1!A1,0)...........

But I can't seem to work out how to search for a characters in a cell if those characters are in a formula, as opposed to just straight up text in a cell............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula for `Sheet2` `B2` : `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,0)),Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$1)`

- `MATCH` will check if A2 appears in "Mark"s values. 0 in "type" specifies an exact match. If not found it returns an error.
- `ISERROR` returns true if `MATCH` returns an error - ie. when value in A2 belongs to Lucy.
- IF returns "Mark" if false (MATCH is NOT an error) and "LUCY" if Match is error.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked! Thanks so much for the detailed run down too, that's super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve that without extra column.

**Sheet2**

```
Row    A             B          C
1      Value         ReferTo    Name
2       =Sheet1!A2   Sheet1!A2  =INDIRECT(MID(B2,1,SEARCH("!",B2,1)+1) & "$1" )
```

If you want to achieve that without extra column, you need to add a piece of VBA code.

1. Go to VBA code editor (ALT+F11)
2. Insert new module (Menu->Insert->Module)
3. Copy and paste below code

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Function GetHeader(ByVal rng As Range, Optional HeaderRow As Integer = 1) As Variant
   Dim i As Integer

       'get referenced row
       i = Range(rng.Formula).Row
       i = (i - HeaderRow) * -1

       GetHeader = Range(rng.Formula).Offset(RowOffset:=i).Value

   End Function
   ```
4. Now go to the *Sheet2* and insert formula into *B2* cell

   ```
   =GetHeader(A2)
   ```

It returns *MARK* or *LUCY* depending on cell referenced by the formula in *A2* cell.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether I understood correctly the source of the problem, but perhaps this would solve it - if you want a formula which tells you the header of the column where is the given number.

```
        =IF(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12;0));0;Sheet1!$A$1)=0;IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$12;0));0;Sheet1!$B$1);IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12;0));0;Sheet1!$A$1))
```

What the formula does: it consists of an "if" statement which checks which of two "match" formulas return something that is not equal to zero. These two "match" formulas are given below:

```
   IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$12;0));0;Sheet1!$A$1)
   IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$B$2:$C$12;0));0;Sheet1!$B$1)
```

Both check whether a number in the cell A1 (in the sheet2) is located in either column A or B (limited range) in the sheet1. Adequately, they return either the header of column 1 or the header of column 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013, you can use FORMULATEXT to examine the formula in A2 directly.

Unfortunately I haven't got it, but here is another suggestion:-

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6=A2)))
```

This does a lookup in the range, finds which column the matching value is in, and uses it to index the row containing MARK and LUCY.

It has the potential advantage that you could extend it to more than two columns.